# I'm getting a linking error here, why is that?

Tags: c++, debugging, overloading

I believe I have all my code correct, but if you see any errors let me know. I'm getting this linking error.

This program manipulates fractions and tests overloading methods.
Thank you, to anyone that will help in advance.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hw05, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Fraction::Fraction(int,int)" (??0Fraction@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Fraction &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVFraction@@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Fraction const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVFraction@@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator==(class Fraction const &)const " (??8Fraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator!=(class Fraction const &)const " (??9Fraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class Fraction __thiscall Fraction::operator*(class Fraction const &)const " (??DFraction@@QBE?AV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class Fraction __thiscall Fraction::operator-(class Fraction const &)const " (??GFraction@@QBE?AV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class Fraction __thiscall Fraction::operator+(class Fraction const &)const " (??HFraction@@QBE?AV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class Fraction __thiscall Fraction::operator/(class Fraction const &)const " (??KFraction@@QBE?AV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator<(class Fraction const &)const " (??MFraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator<=(class Fraction const &)const " (??NFraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator>(class Fraction const &)const " (??OFraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Fraction::operator>=(class Fraction const &)const " (??PFraction@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Fraction::getDenominator(void)const " (?getDenominator@Fraction@@QBEHXZ) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Fraction::getNumerator(void)const " (?getNumerator@Fraction@@QBEHXZ) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Fraction::reduce(void)" (?reduce@Fraction@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: double __thiscall Fraction::returnDecimal(void)const " (?returnDecimal@Fraction@@QBENXZ) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Fraction::setDenominator(int)" (?setDenominator@Fraction@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Fraction::setNumerator(int)" (?setNumerator@Fraction@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Fraction::toString(void)const " (?toString@Fraction@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in Fraction.obj
1>Fraction.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: int __thiscall Fraction::gcd(void)const " (?gcd@Fraction@@ABEHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Fraction::reduce(void)" (?reduce@Fraction@@QAEXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: int __thiscall Fraction::gcd(void)const " (?gcd@Fraction@@ABEHXZ)
1>C:\Users\Matt\Documents\SIUE COMPUTER SCIENCE\CS 240 Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\hw05.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here are my classes.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "string"
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Fraction temp;

Fraction tempTwo;

Fraction tempThree;

cout << "Please enter the first fraction. [numerator denominator]: ";

cin >> temp;

cout << "You entered: " << temp << endl << endl;

cout << "Please enter the second fraction. [numerator denominator]: ";

cin >> tempTwo;

cout << "You entered: " << tempTwo << endl << endl;

cout << "f1 = " << temp << ", f2 = " << tempTwo << endl;

tempThree = (temp + tempTwo);

cout << "f1 + f2 = " << tempThree << " = ";

tempThree.reduce();

cout << tempThree << " = " << tempThree.returnDecimal() << endl;

tempThree = (temp - tempTwo);

cout << "f1 - f2 = " << tempThree << " = ";

tempThree.reduce();

cout << tempThree << " = " << tempThree.returnDecimal() << endl;

tempThree = (temp * tempTwo);

cout << "f1 * f2 = " << tempThree << " = ";

tempThree.reduce();

cout << tempThree << " = " << tempThree.returnDecimal() << endl;

tempThree = (temp / tempTwo);

cout << "f1 / f2 = " << tempThree << " = ";

tempThree.reduce();

cout << tempThree << " = " << tempThree.returnDecimal() << endl << endl;



return 0;


}
```

Fraction.cpp

```
#include "Fraction.h"

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    Fraction::Fraction(const int numerator, const int denominator) {  }

    int Fraction::getNumerator() const {
        return numerator;
    }

    int Fraction::getDenominator() const {
        return denominator;
    }



    void Fraction::setNumerator(const int numerator) {
        this->numerator = numerator;
    }

    void Fraction::setDenominator(const int denominator) {
        this->denominator = denominator;
    }

    string Fraction::toString() const {
        return "";
    }

    int Fraction::gcd() const { 
     int n = numerator; 
     int d = denominator; 
    int tmp; 

     while (d != 0) { 
     tmp = n % d; 
     n = d; 
     d = tmp; 
     } 
     return n; 
    }// end gcd()

    double Fraction::returnDecimal() const {
        double a = (double) getNumerator();
        double b = (double) getDenominator();

        return (a / b);
    }

    void Fraction::reduce()  {

        int a = gcd();
        int b = numerator / a;
        int c = denominator / a;

        setNumerator(b);
        setDenominator(c);

    }

    Fraction Fraction::operator +(const Fraction& f) const {

        Fraction temp;

        int a = getNumerator();
        int b = getDenominator();
        int c = f.getNumerator();
        int d = f.getDenominator();

        int tempOne = b;
        int tempTwo = d;

        a = a * tempTwo;
        b = b * tempTwo;

        c = c * tempOne;
        d = d * tempOne;

        temp.setNumerator(a+c);
        temp.setDenominator(d);

    return temp;

    }

    Fraction Fraction::operator -(const Fraction& f) const {

    Fraction temp;

    int a = getNumerator();
    int b = getDenominator();
    int c = f.getNumerator();
    int d = f.getDenominator();

    int tempOne = b;
    int tempTwo = d;

    a = a * tempTwo;
    b = b * tempTwo;

    c = c * tempOne;
    d = d * tempOne;

    temp.setNumerator(a-c);
    temp.setDenominator(d);

    return temp;

    }

    Fraction Fraction::operator *(const Fraction& f) const {

    Fraction temp;

    temp.setNumerator(getNumerator() * f.getNumerator());
    temp.setDenominator(getDenominator() * f.getDenominator());

    return temp;

    }

    Fraction Fraction::operator /(const Fraction& f) const {

    Fraction temp;

    temp.setNumerator(getNumerator() * f.getDenominator());
    temp.setDenominator(getDenominator() * f.getNumerator());

    return temp;

    }

    bool Fraction::operator ==(const Fraction& f) const {

    return ( (getNumerator() == f.getNumerator()) && (getDenominator() == f.getDenominator()) );

    }

    bool Fraction::operator !=(const Fraction& f) const {

    return !( (getNumerator() == f.getNumerator()) && (getDenominator() == f.getDenominator()) );

    }

    bool Fraction::operator <(const Fraction& f) const {

    double a = getNumerator();
    double b = getDenominator();

    double c = getNumerator();
    double d = getDenominator();

    return ((a/b) < (c/d));

    }

    bool Fraction::operator <=(const Fraction& f) const {

    double a = getNumerator();
    double b = getDenominator();

    double c = getNumerator();
    double d = getDenominator();

    return ((a/b) <= (c/d));

    }

    bool Fraction::operator >(const Fraction& f) const {

    double a = getNumerator();
    double b = getDenominator();

    double c = getNumerator();
    double d = getDenominator();

    return ((a/b) > (c/d));

    }

    bool Fraction::operator >=(const Fraction& f) const {

    double a = getNumerator();
    double b = getDenominator();

    double c = getNumerator();
    double d = getDenominator();

    return ((a/b) >= (c/d));

    }

    ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Fraction& f) {
    out << f.getNumerator() << "/" << f.getDenominator();

    return out;
    }

    istream& operator >>(istream& in, Fraction& f) {    

    int a;
    int b;

    in >> a >> b;

    f.setNumerator(a);
    f.setDenominator(b);

    return in;

    }
```

Fraction.h

```
#ifndef __hw05__Fraction__
#define __hw05__Fraction__


#include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
     class Fraction {

    private:

    int numerator;

    int denominator;

    int gcd() const;

    public:

    Fraction(const int numerator = 0, const int denominator = 0);

    int getNumerator() const;

    int getDenominator() const;

    void setNumerator(const int numerator);

    void setDenominator(const int denominator);

    string toString() const;

    double returnDecimal() const;

    void reduce();

    bool operator ==(const Fraction& f) const;

    bool operator !=(const Fraction& f) const;

    bool operator <(const Fraction& f) const;

    bool operator <=(const Fraction& f) const;

    bool operator >(const Fraction& f) const;

    bool operator >=(const Fraction& f) const;

    Fraction operator +(const Fraction& f) const;

    Fraction operator -(const Fraction& f) const;

    Fraction operator *(const Fraction& f) const;

    Fraction operator /(const Fraction& f) const;

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Fraction&);

    friend istream& operator >>(istream&, Fraction&);

    };

    #endif /* d
```

Comment: Don't `#include "Fraction.cpp"` in your `main.cpp`.

Comment: Please also read [“How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Most of your code is irrelevant for the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you. I will read that before next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fraction.cpp` compiles separately and gets linked later. To use members from there in `main.cpp` you need `Fraction.h`. 
So just remove the line: 
`#include Fraction.cpp`
  
and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Fraction.cpp"
```

Don't `include` source files. `Include` header files (e.g. `Fraction.h`).

**EDIT:**

You seem to have written a lot of code without testing any of it. That's why you're forced to fix bugs one at a time and hope you didn't spend all that time on an approach that turns out to be unworkable.

Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, develop new functionality in isolation, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: That fixed most of the errors, I have updated the original post and am getting this error. 1>------ Build started: Project: hw05, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Fraction.cpp
1>c:\users\matt\documents\siue computer science\cs 240 projects\consoleapplication2\fraction.cpp(66): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  main.cpp

Comment: @tonno5309 if you update the code in the original post, also update the errors in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Your main.cpp is including the fraction.cpp. Therefore the code of fraction.cpp appears twice in the resulting binary which explain the "already defined" messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your function int Fraction::gcd() const; is declared in Fraction.h, but not defined.

Comment: I've added the gcd function to Fraction.cpp, and am now getting this error.    1>------ Build started: Project: hw05, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Fraction.cpp
1>c:\users\matt\documents\siue computer science\cs 240 projects\consoleapplication2\fraction.cpp(66): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  main.cpp